# Using RevolutionPlot3D to visualize a volume

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am working with some calculus students and trying to visualize solids of revolution.   RevolutionPlot3D works well for this,  but I am having a bit of difficulty with the syntax of the command.

The command below gives a "surface" of revolution.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{1/t}, {t, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

It's not a big deal but I'd like to put a "cap" on the top and bottom.

The following command is given in the documentation, a cone that is "capped" at the end.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{t, t}, {t, 1}}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: cone with "cap"]

I would appreciate any advice as to how to implement that for the "solid" I am trying to illustrate.

Comment: RevolutionPlot3D[{{t,1/t},{t-1,1}, {2 t-2,0.5}}, {t, 1, 2}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p1 = RevolutionPlot3D[{1/t}, {t, 1, 2}];
p2 = RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 1}, {t, -1, 1}];
p3 = RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 1/2}, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue];

Show[p1, p2, p3]
```

[image]

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, ViewPoint -> {3, -3, -1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just illustrating use of `RegionPlot3D` and the functionality of regions (and comparison of volume in cylindrical coordinates:

```
r = 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1/z^2 && 1/2 < z < 1;
RegionPlot3D[r, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 1/2, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50,
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> False, Background -> Black, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
reg = ImplicitRegion[r, {x, y, z}];
FullSimplify@Volume[reg]
Integrate[rad, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 1/2, 1},{rad,0,1/z}]
```

[image]

Comment: I figured out your RegionPlot3D code, but the integral at the end has me confused. If I use cylindrical coordinates, I would first do $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2\int_{1/2}^{1/r}\,r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$, which equals $\pi/2$. Then I could get the volume of the cylinder inside with $\pi r^2 h=\pi(1)^2(1/2)=\pi/2$. Adding these together does give a total volume $\pi$. But with cylindrical coordinates, $dV=r dz dr d\theta$, so I don't understand the command Integrate[1, {rad, 1, 2}, {z, 1/2, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}].

Comment: @David thank you! I have corrected my error

Comment: Not quite. I think it should be: Integrate[rad, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 1/2, 1}, {rad, 0, 1/z}].

Comment: @David yes you are right

Comment: Thanks for the help. A lot of helpful suggestions here.